# Can I use Excel function to generate a random word from sentences?

Tags: excel, function, random

Could anybody shows a function to get a random word from a sentence in Excel. I am making a Gap fill exercises. With Column A1 contains the long list of sentences (each sentence is on one row). I need to get column B1 contains list or random word from each sentences from A1. I've been searching around for quite a while but haven't found anything possible. Plus, if it could be done in Excel, the speed is way faster than the others. I think.

Comment: This can be readily accomplished with native worksheet functions. What have you tried?

Comment: I have just tried some Excel functions. For example, SUBSTITUTE(). And have not dealing with writing script in macro. So I thought It has some ready-built function in  Excel. Thank you ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1336-excel-extract-first-last-nth-word.html) shows how to extract the nth word from the given sentence using excel vba.
The function is named "FindWord". Using one more function "CountWord" to count words in the sentence and then using combination of these two as follows

```
=FindWord(A1,RANDBETWEEN(1,CountWord(A1)))
```

(Cell A1 contains the sentence from which word is to be extracted)

Following is the code for functions
(Press Alt+F11, Goto Insert >> Module and then paste following code in module)

```
Function FindWord(Source As String, Position As Integer)
Dim arr() As String
arr = VBA.Split(Source, " ")
xCount = UBound(arr)
If xCount < 1 Or (Position - 1) > xCount Or Position < 0 Then
    FindWord = ""
Else
    FindWord = arr(Position - 1)
End If
End Function
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function CountWord(Source As String)
Dim arr1() As String
arr1 = VBA.Split(Source, " ")
x1count = UBound(arr1)
CountWord = x1count + 1
End Function
```

Source: http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1336-excel-extract-first-last-nth-word.html

Comment: Such a great help from you, Ethun Hunt. I am learning VB.Net and somehow I found that dealing with String. Excel gives pretty much more advantages. So I just started with Excel . Thank you again ~

Comment: It work PERFECT ! Ethun Hunt ~

Answer (score 3):

Here's my custom function that adds some additional functionality.

`Public Function GetRandomWords(TheCell As Range, Optional AllowDuplicates As Boolean, Optional NumberOfWords As Integer, Optional Delimiter As String) As String`

Basically, it will get a random number of words from the cell (between 1 and the maximum number of words in the cell).

By Default, it does not allow duplicates, will get a random number of words, and use the excel default delimiter.

You can change the number of random words to get, the delimiter, and whether or not duplicates are allowed.

You can recalculate the formula using `CTRL`+`ALT`+`SHIFT`+`F9`

You can show the parameters while typing in the formula by using `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`A`

```
Public Function GetRandomWords(TheCell As Range, Optional AllowDuplicates As Boolean, Optional NumberOfWords As Integer, Optional Delimiter As String) As String
If TheCell.CountLarge > 1 Then Set TheCell = TheCell.Cells(1, 1)
Dim Words() As String
Dim NixDupe As New Collection
Dim Helper As Integer
Dim Final As String
Dim x As Integer
If Delimiter = "" Then
    Words = Split(TheCell.Value)
Else
    Words = Split(TheCell.Value, Delimiter:=Delimiter)
End If
For x = 0 To UBound(Words)
    NixDupe.Add Words(x)
Next x
If NumberOfWords = 0 Then
    NumberOfWords = Int((NixDupe.Count) * Rnd + 1)
End If
If (NumberOfWords > NixDupe.Count And Not AllowDuplicates) Or NumberOfWords < 0 Then NumberOfWords = NixDupe.Count
Final = ""
For x = 1 To NumberOfWords
    Helper = Int((NixDupe.Count) * Rnd + 1)
    Final = Final & NixDupe(Helper) & " "
    If Not AllowDuplicates Then
        NixDupe.Remove (Helper)
        If NixDupe.Count = 0 Then Exit For
    End If
Next x
GetRandomWords = Trim(Final)
End Function
```

Using `=GetRandomWords(A1)`

[image: RandomWords]

Using `=GetRandomWords(A1,FALSE,3)`

[image: RandomWords2]

And a different sentence using an absolute cell reference.

`=GetRandomWords($A$1,FALSE,1)`

[image: RandomWords3]

Comment: You are really amzing, @user1274820. Your function has so many options. Thank you for helping me out ~

Answer (score 0):

Using a familiar method of counting words in a phrase to set the upper boundary of a [RANDBETWEEN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685) should get you started on parsing out a random word from a sentance.

[image: random_words]

The formula in B1 is,

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(" "&A1, " ", REPT(" ", LEN(A1))), RANDBETWEEN(1, LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", ""))+1)*LEN(A1), LEN(A1)))
```

Fill down as necessary. You may wish to remove commas and periods before parsing the random words.

Comment: It is amazing the way you make it simple and effective Jeeped !!!